# Trouble compiling OpenACC C code with GCC

Tags: c, openacc

I am having trouble getting some sample C code with openACC directives, which compiles fine with `pgcc -acc`,to compile using `gcc -fopenacc`. I am not sure what the problem is or how to proceed. This code is from an openACC workshop I attended where they used `pgcc` to compile, which means the code works, but as a beginner openACC user, I cannot find a way to make it work with `gcc`.

I am trying to compile the code on OpenSUSE Leap 15.0, using `gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.4.1 20190424 [gcc-7-branch revision 270538]`. I have installed nvptx on Yast. My GPU specs are

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 20%   58C    P0    63W / 250W |   2030MiB / 11177MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   40C    P8    10W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I have tried the commands suggested at [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC), namely `gcc -fopenacc -lm -foffload=-lm code.c` and variations of it, but there always seems to be something wrong. The variations I've taken from other sites, which involve changing the used flags, do not seem to work either. Using the aforementioned `gcc -fopenacc -lm -foffload=-lm code.c` compiles, but the code does not seem to run properly.

The code I'm trying to run simulates laplacian heat expansion on a metal plate. It uses `#include <math.h>` so I included the `-lm` flag. The relevant code (by John Urbanic, PSC 2014) in `main()` looks like this

```
    int i, j;                                            // grid indexes
    int max_iterations;                                  // number of iterations
    int iteration=1;                                     // current iteration
    double dt=100;                                       // largest change in t
    struct timeval start_time, stop_time, elapsed_time;  // timers

    printf("Maximum iterations [100-4000]?\n");
    scanf("%d", &max_iterations);

    gettimeofday(&start_time,NULL); // Unix timer

    initialize();                   // initialize Temp_last including boundary conditions

    // do until error is minimal or until max steps
    #pragma acc data copy(Temperature_last), create(Temperature)
    while ( dt > MAX_TEMP_ERROR && iteration <= max_iterations ) {

        // main calculation: average my four neighbors
        #pragma acc kernels
        for(i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j <= COLUMNS; j++) {
                Temperature[i][j] = 0.25 * (Temperature_last[i+1][j] + Temperature_last[i-1][j] +
                                            Temperature_last[i][j+1] + Temperature_last[i][j-1]);
            }
        }

        dt = 0.0; // reset largest temperature change

        // copy grid to old grid for next iteration and find latest dt
        #pragma acc kernels
        for(i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++){
            for(j = 1; j <= COLUMNS; j++){
          dt = fmax( fabs(Temperature[i][j]-Temperature_last[i][j]), dt);
          Temperature_last[i][j] = Temperature[i][j];
            }
        }

        // periodically print test values
        if((iteration % 100) == 0) {
            #pragma acc update host(Temperature)
        track_progress(iteration);
        }

    iteration++;
    }
```

After compiling with `gcc -fopenacc -lm -foffload=-lm code.c`, running `./a.out` prints `"Maximum iterations [100-4000]?[\n]"` to console. After that it seems to just spin. I don't think it even accepts the input from `scanf` I try to give it. Have to `ctrl+c` to end. Other commands I've tried are `gcc -fopenacc laplace_acc.c` which yells at me because of `fmax`. I have omitted a huge part of the code to keep it brief, but do let me know if you need more of it.

I apologize if this is too basic of a question or if I'm just missing something very obvious, but I am truly lost. I am not very familiar with using directives. In addition, I have found it hard to find resources on compiling openACC with GCC, since it seems quite common to use Intel or PGI for this instead.

Comment: maybe try to debug that code. Would be surprising that it locks up on `scanf`

Comment: "I don't think it even accepts the input from scanf I try to give it": what happens? can't you type numbers in the console? (would be good to check return code of scanf as well just in case someone enters "waffles" instead of a number)

Comment: I can type anything and pressing enter registers in the terminal, but I don't think the scanf line is even running. The whole terminal becomes irresponsive and the computer becomes slow, but it is unclear what is happening. I'm running gdb, breaking at the scanf it is not even recognizing any variables as symbols I don't think. Are you aware of whether the compilation commands I am using are correct? I was thinking it was because of the commands since using `pgcc` works fine on the exact same code (on a cluster machine though).

Comment: oh you have to add the `-g` flag to be able to debug your program BTW (or there won't be any symbols)

Comment: Oh yeah, I did, sorry. I forgot to `run` on gdb, completely my bad. It seems to be running `scanf` actually, and actually reading in the value.

Comment: I get this after continueing ```Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/librt.so.1
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=22095cc8672f70252879bbf6c62f9d4f3026c579"
[New Thread 0x7fffef6b6700 (LWP 21176)]
[New Thread 0x7fffeeeb5700 (LWP 21177)]
[New Thread 0x7fffee633700 (LWP 21178)]
```

Comment: That message is probably harmless, but you should be able to avoid it by installing the wanted external debug info.  Quite possibly the command suggested for doing so will actually work.

Comment: I just tried, getting "No provider of 'debuginfo(build-id)=22095cc8672f70252879bbf6c62f9d4f3026c579' found. ['--plus-content debug'?]
"

Comment: You might try replacing "#pragma acc kernels" with "#pragma acc parallel loop".  While I believe GNU has gotten better in the latest 9.0 release, they did have difficultly with the compiler analysis required to determine loop independence for "kernels" so would run these loops sequentially and may be why it seems to hang.  They do a much better job with the "parallel" directive since this is the user guiding where to put parallelism rather than needing the compiler to discover it.